# Hibernate query: find equal objects

Tags: hibernate

I have a Hibernate class which has a reasonably complicated implementation of `equals()`. Is it possible to write a query that returns all instances of this class that have at least one other equal object, where equality is defined by the implementation of `equals()`?

**Update**
Evidently this is not possible. As an alternative, is it possible to retrieve all instances of a particular class that have equal property values. For example:

> Get all instances of User that have
>   the same name

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3):

Via query? No.

Hibernate will not use your `equals()` for loading at all, actually, unless your entity is part of collection.

**Update** (based on question edit):

Yes, that is possible for **mapped** properties. You'll need to use a [group by / having](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping) and [a subquery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries). Something like:

```
from Person p
 where name in (
  select p2.name from Person p2
   group by p2.name
   having count(p2.id) > 1
)
```

Comment: +1 Hibernate is an ORM, it maps data to your objects, not the other way around.